# Is it grammatical to use "would be" in a conditional clause?

Tags: grammar, conditionals, clauses, would

Is it grammatically correct to include "would be" in a conditional clause?

> Your physician may recommend you to be evaluated if you would potentially be a candidate for this vaccine.

Comment: Yes, it's grammatical. But the entire sentence is awkward and unidiomatic. Far more natural would be one of the following: (1) *Your physician may recommend you as a candidate for this vaccine.* (2) *Your physician may recommend an evaluation to see if you are a candidate for this vaccine.* Note that you can replace *are* with *would be* in the second sentence, but it's not as common.

Comment: Thank you, can you give me your fb ?

Comment: It's redundant, overblown.

Comment: Pretty typical of CYA medical prose. "Ask your doctor", they always say, when it takes a week to get a return call.

Comment: The use of the infinitive 'to be' is incorrect in your sentence and it would be better to surround 'potentially' with parenthetic commas. To me "Your physician may recommend you _be_ evaluated if you would, potentially, be a candidate for this vaccine" would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to say.

If you're trying to say that the evaluation is will determine if you're a candidate, you should include that detail.

> Your physician may recommend you to be evaluated to determine if you would potentially be a candidate for this vaccine.

But if your intent is that the physician already feels that you would be a candidate, and then recommends a further evaluation, you it would be better to invert the sentence to make the order of actions clearer.

> If you would potentially be a candidate for this vaccine, your physician may recommend you to be evaluated.

Answer (score -1):

It can ideally be "Your physician may recommend you to be evaluated if you are potentially a candidate for this vaccine./ ...if you are a potential candidate for this vaccination"etc. However, going against the conventional grammar,

"Your physician may recommend you to be evaluated if you would potentially be a candidate for this vaccine", should be acceptable, except in the examinations/ English tests for students.